# Style applied for select option in Firefox browser alone?

Tags: html, styles, cross-browser

I have select option in my form like below,

```
<select>
<option class="hdng">Number</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option class="hdng">Alphabets</option>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
</select>
```

in my style i applied style heading,

```
.hdng
{
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Above style is applied in Firefox browser alone. Remaining browsers the style doesn't supported.
Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Works fine for me, FireFox 8.0, http://jsfiddle.net/sVKjv/

Comment: Please do a search before you post a question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=style+select+option

Comment: Sorry working in FF alone. remaining browsers not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails for me in Chrome 16 also, consider using optgroups which tend to have better styling support & are semantically correct for what your trying to do.

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Number">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Alphabets">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</optgroup>    
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVKjv/1/